# How to write an array to cvs without brackets?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an array as `A=[1 2 3]` and I want to write it to a cvs file such that the output must appear without brackets `[` and `]`. This is my code but it 
appears brackets. How should I fix it in python and pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
id = []
content=[]
id.append(1)
content.append(A)
id.append(2)
content.append(A)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'content': content})
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, columns=['id', 'content'])
```

Current output

`id,content
1, [1 2 3]
2, [1 2 3]`

Expected output

`id,content
1, 1 2 3
2, 1 2 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `list`s to joined `string`s:

```
content = [' '.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in content]
print (content)
['1 2 3', '1 2 3']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'content': content})
print (df)
   id content
0   1   1 2 3
1   2   1 2 3
```